# Alternative to Wisconsin Brick Cheese

Tags: substitutions, cheese, pizza

I just came across a [pizza recipe](https://www.seriouseats.com/2017/02/how-to-make-detroit-style-pizza.html) that requires Wisconsin Brick Cheese.

It kind of looks like Cheddar or Emmental, however I do not know by taste.

As I am living in Portugal, finding that cheese is not that easy, so I am wondering if there are alternatives to this type of cheese, ideally from European countries, if from Portugal, the better (but I am open to alternatives available worldwide).

Comment: The page you link to gives some (admittedly US-centric) alternatives, with a 50/50 mix of low-moisture Mozzarella and Jack as best option. Cheddar apparently did not taste quite right.

Comment: Brick! It's been ages since I've had good Wisconsin brick cheese, but I do remember what it tastes like. I'll have a think and see if I can answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brick is one of those cheeses that should get more distribution. It's slightly soft and melts well, with a slight butteriness and tinge of acidity. Aged brick gets a slightly ripe flavor and smell. The closest cheese I can think of to a decent aged Brick is an aged Havarti. Similar softness, and not far off in flavor compared to other cheeses, and it should be widely available.